# Another problem with templates

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

template<class T>
class IsPolymorphic
{
 template<class T>
 struct Check
 {
  enum {value = false};
 };

 template<class T>
 struct Check<T*>
 {
  enum {value = true};
 };
public: 
 enum {value = Check<T>::value};

};

template<bool flag, class T, class U>
struct Select
{
 typedef T value_type;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct Select<true,T,U>
{
 typedef U value_type;
};

template<class T, bool isPoly = IsPolymorphic<T>>
class Container
{
public:
 typedef typename Select<isPoly,T,T*>::value_type value_type;
 Container(){}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 //cout << IsPolymorphic<int*>::value;
 Container<int> c;
 return 0;
}
```

I'm getting following errors:
**Error 3 error C2512: 'Container' : no appropriate default constructor available**
**Error 2 error C2133: 'c' : unknown size**
**Error 1 error C2975: 'Container' : invalid template argument for 'isPoly', expected compile-time constant expression**

As for these errors:
no 3 - clearly there is dflt ctor - so what's going on?
no 2 - why is it unknown size? I've specified int as a type so why would it be unknown?
no 1 - exactly as no 2
Thanks for any help with this.
**Thanks to all of you for helping me in solving this problem**

Comment: Search for `>>` in there. Whitespace is your friend.

Comment: You really want to reimplement standard library functionality? In particular, type traits???

Comment: @Potatoswatter ;) Just trying to learn something new everyday. ;)

Comment: OK :v) so long as you're having fun…

Comment: IsPolymorphic obviously only determines if `T` is a pointer or not, and would be more appropriately called `IsPointer`. The implementation is also a bit too complicated: why forward the deduction to a nested class (there are errors with that), if you could just specialize `IsPointer` itself (rename `Check` and erase the class surrounding it). - The `Select` struct seems to be counterintuitive, selecting the last argument if true (contrary to ternary operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<class T, bool isPoly = IsPolymorphic<T>::value>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe, litb's answer is the one you should be selecting for the benefit of all future references

Comment: thanks. I think you were one of the first who answered so whatever @A-ha does, I think you deserve the accept-mark too. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several errors:

- You try to hide the template parameter `T` by an inner declaration of that name
- You use `IsPolymorphic<T>` intead of `IsPolymorphic<T>::value`
- What *@potatoswatter* says.

Comment: @litb Thanks for your answer I upvoted it. I really value your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean:

```
bool isPoly = IsPolymorphic<T>::value
```